# .net6.0 API Empty Json body on large requests

Tags: json, .net, api, iis, asp.net-core-6.0

Good morning,

I have a bit of an odd one I am scratching my head about at the moment, and was wondering if anyone faced something similar in the past. I am working on a rest API in .net6.0, and we have noticed failures on response which are approximately larger than 200MB of JSON (whether an API should return packets this large is a different topic, and we are having discussions about this too).

The main symptom is that the calls come back as a 200, so successful, and I can also see from the API logs that all the processing was completed, however the response body is empty. I can replicate this pointing different clients to the API (e.g. Postman). There is nothing helpful in either the Event Viewer nor the IIS logs.

What I have tried, unsuccessfully:

- The API is hosted on a Windows Server 2012 (IIS 8.5) machine, but I also machine to replicate this on a Windows Server 2019 (IIS 10.5) one, so not a compatibility version in terms of IIS version.
- Tried adding the following to the *web.config* file as it resolved a similar thing I had in an older framework:

  ```
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="10800" /> 
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      <!-- maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes -->
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
  ```
- Increased the Response buffering limit in IIS's ASP configuration.

None of those managed to resolve my issue.

One thing I did notice though, is that if I switch the settings to use Kestrel, updating the web.config file to use OutOfProcess, my problem disappears.
While I don't want to use Kestrel, this leads me to believe it's on the IIS front.

Would anyone have seen something like this before and have an idea of what I might be missing? Any advice really appreciated on this one.

Thank you,
Alex.

Comment: There may be a lot of repetition of property names in your large JSON response,  you can try enabling gzip compression on your response. The gzip algorithm is particularly good at compression when there are repetitive strings fed to it.

Comment: Hi samwu, thank you for that. In production we have this enabled, and it is quite useful. But I'm just perplexed this started happening when we migrated (read rewrote) the project to the latest framework (200MB seems low to be a set limit and I hope there is a way to adjust this).

Comment: It is difficult to troubleshoot your problem , I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Yes, an easy time waster, I will heed your advice and open a case with them. Thank you very much. Will update here once I get an answer.